# What is a UINavigationTransitionView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5, rotation, transition

I'm trying to debug some strange rotation behaviour in a view. Looking up the view hierarchy I can see that the rotation is occurring in an instance of UINavigationTransitionView. What is this view? Is it related to UINavigationController?

My hierarchy looks like this:

```
MPMovieView
  UIView
    UIViewControllerWrappper
      UINavigationTransitionView
        UILayoutContainerView
          UIWindow
```

Comment: @davedelong knows a thing or two about UIKit. :-)

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK UINavigationTransitionView is a class used to animate UINavigationController child views around. It usually contain one or two UIViewControllerWrapperView's , each of these containing your actual UIViewController.view
If you subclass UINavigationController and override pushViewControllerAnimated: , you can log the hierarchy before and after calling [super pushViewControllerAnimated:], you'll notice the VC being pushed rect change from {0, 20, 320, 480} to {-320, 20, 320, 480} 
Although its nice to understand how it works, as it is private API, its very likely to change between iOS versions, so you should not make your rotation solution based on this behavior. Post a new question with the actual rotation issue and we can help you solve it, without using private API

Answer (score 0):

Very often, Apple uses private classes inside of public classes, to manage internal behavior. This is one of those cases. There's no public class called UINavigationTranstionView. I'd either look elsewhere for the bug, or file a radar, if you are convinced that Apple's at fault. If you decide to continue to look at your code, consider posting some of that code and a description of your issue, here so we can help.